# Extracting a number from an unspaced string in Python

Tags: python

I need to extracted a number from an unspaced string that has the number in brakets for example:

```
"auxiliary[0]"
```

The only way I can think of is:

```
def extract_num(s):    
   s1=s.split["["]
   s2=s1[1].split["]"]
   return int(s2[0])
```

Which seems very clumsy, does any one know of a better way to do it? (The number is always in "[ ]" brakets)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression (with the built-in [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)):

```
import re

bracketed_number = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\]')

def extract_num(s):
    return int(bracketed_number.search(s).group(1))
```

The pattern matches a literal `[` character, followed by 1 or more digits (the `\d` escape signifies the digits character group, `+` means 1 or more), followed by a literal `]`. By putting parenthesis around the `\d+` part, we create a capturing group, which we can extract by calling `.group(1)` ("get the first capturing group result").

Result:

```
>>> extract_num("auxiliary[0]")
0
>>> extract_num("foobar[42]")
42
```

Comment: I thoght about it but I wasn't sure if using this will require me to install a lib that might not be on other computers. Is this the case or the "re" comes build in the Python release?

Comment: @GuyKovel: It is a standard library that comes with Python; I linked you to the documentation. Python comes with batteries included! :-)

Comment: @GuyKovel: Did this work for you so far? Anything I need to add to the explanation?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regular expression to get the number.  See docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Something like:

```
import re
def extract_num(s):
  m = re.search('\[(\d+)\]', s)
  return int(m.group(1))
```

Comment: Your search will return '[0]' instead of '0'; is that intentional?

Comment: Ah, good point.  Glad I wrote "Something like" :).  I'll adjust it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
print a[-2]
```

---

```
print a[a.index(']') - 1]
```

---

```
print a[a.index('[') + 1]
```

Comment: ``foobar[42]`` will fail with these.

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\]',"auxiliary[0]"):
    do_sth(number)
```